# C++ array as parameter - why do you only need to specify "outer" dimension

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to figure out multidimensional arrays and specifically how to fill them by passing them to functions. It's all very unintuitive, but the unintuitivest thing of all, which doesn't make any sense at all to me is:

Why do you have to specify the number of columns, but not the number of rows when passing an 2d array as a parameter? I've probably looked at five or more forum threads that give the syntax, but none of them explained the reasoning behind it. I am okay with the compiler needing to know the size of an array to operate on it, but isn't a bidimensional array basically an array of arrays?

Comment: Note also for the n-dimensional case (where n>2), it's not just the "outer" dimension you need to specify - it's better to say that you need to specify "all dimensions except the innermost one" (e.g. `my4darray[][X][Y][Z]`), because the compiler needs to know all the dimensions except for one to do proper indexing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we need to specify the column size when passing a 2D array as a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813494/why-do-we-need-to-specify-the-column-size-when-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> but isn't a bidimensional array basically an array of arrays?

It is.

But the compiler needs to know the size really just in order to be able to perform pointer arithmetic correctly when indexing into the array (well, apart from allocation of course, but we are speaking in the context of functions here), since multidimensional arrays are continuous in memory. `int arr[2][3]` declares that there be 3 `int`s in a row, and two pieces of 3-`int` rows follow each other.

Now what happens to arrays when you pass them to a function is that they decay into a pointer. But it's only logical that the first (innermost) dimension decays into one, because we can index (in theory) an arbitrarily long array using a a single pointer to its first element.

If, however, there are multiple dimensions, then the compiler **needs** those dimensions so that it can perform pointer arithmetic on further dimensions.

[Here is](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) something you should read in addition.

Comment: Side note: once you get this, it will be the single most intuitive thing you have ever learnt in programming. :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes, there are. And how are they relevant here?

Comment: technically, arrays are just an abstraction on pointers. They aren't directly relevant here, I was replying to your comment about understanding arrays being the most initiative thing. Being that the OP is working in C++, pointers are something [s]he's gonna encounter sooner or later. If you want to succeed in C or C++, you need to know about pointers as well.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a great response. Just need to digest it a smidget: the only information the compiler actually needs is the starting adress of the array and the byte size of whatever data it contains? It doesn't need to know how many bytes the array occupies in total?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist No, it doesn't. If you have a base address and an element size, you can index. The base address is of type "pointer to the tail dimensions of the array" and it points to the first element of the array (it's an `int *` if the array is an `int [N]`, it's an `int (*)[3]` if an array is an `int[N][3]`, etc., and the element size is `sizeof(array[0])`, i. e. `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int [3])`, respectively.) If there was bound checking in C and C++ (as there isn't), the compiler would need the size to check if the index is out of bounds. But that's really just meta-data.

Comment: Ok I think the light bulb just lit up. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist You're welcome. Each time a C(++) programmer understands arrays, a kitten killed by people casting the return value of `malloc()` is resurrected.

Answer (score 6):

When you pass an array parameter to a function, the parameter gets converted to a pointer to the first element of an array.

A two-dimensional array in C++ is really an array of arrays. So the parameter you're passing is a pointer to the array containing the first column.

To access the second column, the pointer must be incremented past the first column. To do that the compiler must know the size of the column, just as it must know the size of any other array element.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to specify all dimensions besides the first one.  The reason is that the compiler won't know how much memory to allocate otherwise.

For a detailed answer, see the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2562111/1822214

Comment: It also won't know the size of the first one to skip over if you want the second index.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you need to think of array declaration in terms of pointers.

When you pass an array as an argument to a function, it will decay into a pointer to the first element of the array.

```
int intArray[3]
// Decays into
int * intArray;
```

Which are equivalent in the mind of the compiler. When you refer to an array by index, the compiler will actually use pointer arithmetic to determine which slot of memory to go to.

Now with your 2D array, it actually decays into a pointer to the first element as well. If the array is declared to be on the stack, the 2D storage is actually in Row Major format. This is something many people new to C++ overlook. The compiler needs to know the column value in order to perform pointer arithmetic to find the element you are looking for. C++ arrays are not objects and this my friend is why there are no length checks for arrays in C++.